# tikzpicture add curved arrow in INTERVAL

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows, tikz-graphdrawing

I am currently working on a slide in which I need to add a curved arrow in the interval as below

[image]

Pardon my poor drawing skill in MS paint...

This is my current attempt

```
    \draw[->, thick] (-0.1,0) -- (1.1,0);\\

    \foreach \x/\xtext in {0/0,1/1}

    \draw[thick] (\x,0.5pt) -- (\x,-0.5pt) node[below] {\xtext};

    \draw[bend right=90, ultra thick, blue] (0,0.1) -- (1,0.1);
```

I researched and found bend might work, but it does not work in the interval (only works for node)

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work if you use `--`, but it works with a `to` path, i.e. `(x1,y1) to (x2,y2)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->, thick] (-0.1,0) -- (1.1,0);
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {0/0,1/1} 
       \draw[thick] (\x,0.5pt) -- (\x,-0.5pt) node[below] {\xtext};

    \draw[bend left=90, ultra thick, blue] (0,0.1) to (1,0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```